# model validate in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-model

I have this simple script just to trying out the backbone validation functionality, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
Client = Backbone.Model.extend({
    validate: function(attrs){
        if (attrs.age < 18){
            return console.log("Too young to be a client");
        }
    }
});

client = new Client;
client.set({age:15});
```

Nothing is logged in the console. What's wrong?. 
Thanks!.-

Answer (score 1):

Just pass an option, try this `client.set({age:2},{validate:true})`

Answer (score 0):

Validation happens on save, or if you explicitly pass the option `validate: true`.

Either call `client.save()` after set, or pass `{ validate: true }` as the second argument to `set`.